# My newcommand does not work within other environments (align*)

Tags: errors

Minimal Example that demonstrates the problem:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%%% variable declaration:
\newlength{\temp}%
\newlength{\tempp}%
\newlength{\Flinewidth}%
\setlength{\Flinewidth}{0.5pt}%
\newlength{\Fraiseheight}%
\setlength{\Fraiseheight}{1ex}%
\addtolength{\Fraiseheight}{-\Flinewidth}%
\newlength{\Fantecedentheight}%
\newlength{\Fconsequentdepth}%
\newsavebox{\Fantecedent}%
\newsavebox{\Fconsequent}%

%%% conditional stroke \Fconditional[content]{consequent}{antecedent}:
\newcommand{\Fconditional}[3][]%
{%
  \unskip
  \sbox{\Fantecedent}{%
    \rule{0pt}{\baselineskip}% this is a strut
    \ensuremath{#3}}%
  \settoheight{\Fantecedentheight}{%
    \rule{0pt}{\baselineskip}%
    \ensuremath{#3}}%  
  \sbox{\Fconsequent}{%
    \rule[-0.3\baselineskip]{0pt}{0.3\baselineskip}% this is a strut
    \ensuremath{#2}}%
  \settodepth{\Fconsequentdepth}{%
    \rule[-0.3\baselineskip]{0pt}{0.3\baselineskip}%
    \ensuremath{#2}}%
  \setlength{\temp}{\lineskip}%
  \addtolength{\temp}{\Fantecedentheight}%
  \addtolength{\temp}{\Fconsequentdepth}%
  \setlength{\tempp}{\temp}%
  \addtolength{\tempp}{-\Fraiseheight}%
  \mbox{%
    \ensuremath{#1\unskip}%
    \kern-\Flinewidth%
    \rule[-\tempp]{\Flinewidth}{\temp}%
    \settowidth{\temp}{\usebox{\Fconsequent}\\\usebox{\Fantecedent}}%
    \parbox[t]{\temp}{\usebox{\Fconsequent}\\\usebox{\Fantecedent}}}%
}%

\begin{document}
  $\Fconditional[A]{B}{C}$
  $\Fconditional[A]{B}{C\Fconditional{D}{E}}$
  \begin{align*}
    \Fconditional[A]{B}{C}
  \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

This command does exactly what it is supposed to do as called in in-line maths mode like so:

```
$\Fconditional[A]{B}{C}$
```

Thanks to the comment about removing definitions from the macro, the command now also works nested in itself like so:

```
$\Fconditional[A]{B}{C\Fconditional{D}{E}}$
```

However if I call the same command within an align* environment like so:

```
\begin{align*}
  \Fconditional[A]{B}{C}
\end{align*}
```

I get the following error message:

> ! Misplaced alignment tab character &.
>   \math@cr@@@ ->&
>                 \omit \global \advance \row@ \@ne \ifst@rred \nonumber \fi \i...
>   l.51   \end{align*}

This happens regardless of whether I actually use any & characters in the align* environment. Ignoring the error produces part of the output.

Sorry I did not include a proper minimal example earlier.

Comment: AMS environments are executed _twice_ so that things get measured so all your `\new...` will generate errors the second internal run. It is almost always a bad idea to have `\newsavebox` and `\newlength` inside macros as that means you allocate new registers each time, the intended usage is that you allocate the registers you need at the start and re-use the same registers.

Comment: OK if you need further help please edit the question so it is a complete document using ams alignment and generating the error.

Comment: sorry, what you used, I just meant any of align or align* or alignedat etc from amsmath package. But don't just _say_ you get an error in that case, make a document that shows the error.

Comment: So... moving the \new... commands outside the macro has fixed half the problem. I have updated the question to reflect this, and included a minimal working example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The use of `\\` in

```
\settowidth{\temp}{\usebox{\Fconsequent}\\\usebox{\Fantecedent}}%
```

makes no sense. There is no "context" there to give meaning to a newline.

Consequently, the `\\` is "captured" by the `align` environment, leading to the error.

I assume you want `\temp` to assume the maximum width of `\Fconsequent` and `\Fantecedent`. Replacing the `\settowidth` expression by the TeX construct

```
\ifdim\wd\Fconsequent>\wd\Fantecedent
  \setlength{\temp}{\wd\Fconsequent}%
 \else
  \setlength{\temp}{\wd\Fantecedent}%
\fi
```

will do the job. I assume there are more elegant, more LaTeXy ways...

Comment: That makes sense. And yes, I want `\temp` to take on the width of the wider of `\Fconsequent` and `\Fantecedent` whichever that is. If somebody does still know how to that in a "LaTeXy" way, I would appreciate it... I will have a think about it myself.

Comment: One not so elegant way to solve the problem that does not rely on pure TeX, is to measure the width of `\usebox{\Fconsequent}` and `\usebox{\Fantecedent}` separately using `\settowidth{}{}` and then placing both lengths as vertical struts into a `\makebox{}` the height of which is determined by it's contents and can be measured with `\settoheight{}{}`...

Comment: You could also use `\settowidth{\temp}{\shortstack{\usebox{\Fconsequent}\\\usebox{\Fantecedent}}}%` to get a solution which is nearer to your original idea. Furthermore, the [`ifthen`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/ifthen.pdf) package provides a means to compare lengths in a LaTeXy way.